# Centering text in C# console app only working with some input

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, console-application, centering

I am having a problem with centering text in a C#.NET4 console app.

This is my method for centering the text:

```
private static void centerText(String text)
{
    int winWidth = (Console.WindowWidth / 2);
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,"+winWidth+"}", text));
}
```

However, I just get the output as it would have been outputted normally.
If I however use this line:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,"+winWidth+"}", "text"));
```

The "text" gets centered as it should.

I am calling `centerText` with these two methods:

```
private static void drawStars()
{
    centerText("*********************************************");
}
private static void title(string location)
{
    drawStars();
    centerText("+++ Du er nu her: " + location + "! +++");
    drawStars();
}
```

Comment: The problem occurs when/because your text is longer that half the width of the screen.

Comment: @DaveShaw There is a bigger problem than that: the text width was never even part of the centering.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
private static void centerText(String text)
{
    Console.Write(new string(' ', (Console.WindowWidth - text.Length) / 2));
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

The problem with your initial code was that your text *starts* in the screen center. You want the center of the text to be there.

You're going to do a bit more work if you want to print entire paragraphs centered like this.

Comment: For Paragraphs:
        private static void centerText(String text)
        {
            Console.Write(new string(' ', (Console.WindowWidth - text.Length) / 2));
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }

        private static void centerpara(String para)
        {
            char[] delims = new[] { '\r', '\n' };
            string[] strings = para.Split(delims, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (string X in strings)
            {
                centerText(X);
            }
        }

Answer (score 3):

I have my own method for calling console headers:

```
public static void Header(string title, string subtitle = "", ConsoleColor color = ConsoleColor.White)
{
    int windowWidth = 90 - 2;
    string titleContent = String.Format("║{0," + ((windowWidth / 2) + (title.Length / 2)) + "}{1," + (windowWidth - (windowWidth / 2) - (title.Length / 2) + 1) + "}", title, "║");
    string subtitleContent = String.Format("║{0," + ((windowWidth / 2) + (subtitle.Length / 2)) + "}{1," + (windowWidth - (windowWidth / 2) - (subtitle.Length / 2) + 1) + "}", subtitle, "║");

    Console.WriteLine("╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗");
    Console.WriteLine(titleContent);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subtitle))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(subtitleContent);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝");
}
```

Then you call it like this `YourStaticClass.Header("Test", "Version 1.0");`

it should look like this:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                                          Test                                          ║
║                                      Version 1.0                                       ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

You can replace the `90` in `windowsWidth` with `Console.WindowWidth`

**UPDATE** - February 2019 - code cleaned and made dynamic size

```
/// <summary>
/// Application header, also sets the console title
/// </summary>
/// <param name="title">Title of application</param>
/// <param name="subtitle">Subtitle of application</param>
/// <param name="foreGroundColor">Foreground color</param>
public static void Header(string title, string subtitle = "", ConsoleColor foreGroundColor = ConsoleColor.White, int windowWidthSize = 90)
{
    Console.Title = title + (subtitle != "" ? " - " + subtitle : "");
    string titleContent = CenterText(title, "║");
    string subtitleContent = CenterText(subtitle, "║");
    string borderLine = new String('═', windowWidthSize - 2);

    Console.ForegroundColor = foreGroundColor;
    Console.WriteLine($"╔{borderLine}╗");
    Console.WriteLine(titleContent);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subtitle))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(subtitleContent);
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"╚{borderLine}╝");
    Console.ResetColor();
}

/// <summary>
/// Align content to center for console. Can be used with decoration if used inside menu or header
/// </summary>
/// <param name="content">Content to center</param>
/// <param name="decorationString">Left and right decoration, default is empty/none</param>
/// <returns>Center aligned text</returns>
public static string CenterText(string content, string decorationString = "", int windowWidthSize = 90)
{
    int windowWidth = windowWidthSize - (2 * decorationString.Length);
    return String.Format(decorationString + "{0," + ((windowWidth / 2) + (content.Length / 2)) + "}{1," + (windowWidth - (windowWidth / 2) - (content.Length / 2) + decorationString.Length) + "}", content, decorationString);
}
```

Comment: Though this not the accepted answer, it is definitely something to add to my library. But I'd recommend generating the border dynamically, too ;) +1

Comment: Nice. It was meant as a hint but you updated your answer anyway. Now it's easier for other people to find a nice solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Just want to point out that you're not passing the window size to CenterText in the respective Header calls.

Comment: Yes, it has it's value set to 90 by default: int windowWidthSize = 90

Answer (score 2):

The text passed in may have whitespace such as `\r\n`, then remove that before calling the write such as

```
string textClean = Regex.Replace(text, @"([\r\n])", string.Empty);

// Then center on text clean
```

Comment: While this is good advice, it doesn't appear to be the root problem here.  This should therefore probably be just a comment.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't answer the question but it's good to point it out. It's something you quickly forget when you're doing stuff like this. I'd use this: `string cleanText = text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);`