# How to display multiple line string in the center of the console

Tags: c#

I'm writing a C# game in console where objects have string type members that hold their models for example:

```
string model = "####\n####\n####\n####";
```

And I want to dipslay them in various places but when I use `Console.SetCursorPosition()` and `Console.Write(model)` first line displays where I had set the position but next lines are written at the beginning of new line and output looks like this:

```
          ####
####
####
####
```

I tried using @ prefix but it doesn't work. Is there a way to display this string as a square in the middle of the console?

Comment: You obviously can guess why its happening. as such you will need to rethink your problem. A low tech approach might be to split add spaces, and rejoin `string.Join(Environment.NewLine,model.Split('\n').Select(x => $"{new string(' ',<Count>}{x}"));` Another approach, is to abandon writing this all in the one write statement, and iterate the split string to the right console coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Using \t in string:

```
string model = "\t\t\t####\n\t\t\t####\n\t\t\t####\n\t\t\t####";
```

The output is:

```
        ####
        ####
        ####
        ####
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847960/centering-text-in-c-sharp-console-app-only-working-with-some-input).
Base on the answer by Roman Starkov should be able to achieve what you need in a single line. 
For multiple lines, try this:

```
static void CenterText(string text)
{
    Console.Write(new string(' ', (Console.WindowWidth - text.Length) / 2));
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string model = "####\n####\n####\n####";
    foreach (var m in model.split("\n"))
    {
        CenterText(m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a little utility method which splits the string based on `'\n'` and apply `SetCursorPosition` for each block.

For example,

```
static void WriteInCenter(string data)
{
  foreach (var model in data.Split('\n'))
  {
    Console.SetCursorPosition((Console.WindowWidth - model.Length) / 2, Console.CursorTop);
    Console.WriteLine(model);
  }
}
```

You could now invoke the method as

```
string model = "####\n####\n####\n####";
WriteInCenter(model);
```